# how to join 3 tables in laravel using eloquent hasmanythrough or hasonethrough

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, model, relationship

this is my tables look like

| departments | course | subjects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
| head | department_id | course_id |
|  | course_name | subject_code |

in my models this is how I do it but seems not working and I don't know why:

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        subjectlist::class,
        department::class,
        'id',
        'course_id',
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

The output when I try to use `hasOneThrough`:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "department_name": "Business",
    "head": "John smith",
    "email": "smith@gmail.com",
    "contact_number": "09300282103",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "subject_list": {
        "id": 1,
        "course_id": 1,
        "subject_code": "Math1",
        "description": "math test",
        "year_type": 1,
        "price": "200.00",
        "units": "5.00",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "laravel_through_key": 1
    }
}
```

I wan't the output should be like this please help me how to do it:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "department_name": "Business",
    "head": "John smith",
    "email": "smith@gmail.com",
    "contact_number": "09300282103",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "subject_list": {
        "id": 1,
        "course_id": 1,
        "subject_code": "Math1",
        "description": "math test",
        "year_type": 1,
        "price": "200.00",
        "units": "5.00",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "laravel_through_key": 1
    },
    "department": {
        "id": 1,
        "department_name": "ComputerScience"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you show your model query code.

Answer (score 0):

Relationship between your tables are like
Subject as a Course
Course has a Department
and Subject has a department through course

Relation For Your Subject Model

```
public function Course() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
public function Department() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Department::class, Course::class)
}
```

Relation For Your Course Model

```
public function Subject() {
    return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
}
public function Department() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

Relation For Your Department Model

```
public function Course() {
    return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
}
```

For farther info refer to laravel eloquent relationships documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through